# Android-Wear icons are not showing up

Tags: java, android, xml, wear-os

So I developed an AndroidWear App with the LG G-Watch, the icons and everything else were working properly. Now I switched to the Asus Zenwatch 2 and could deploy my app without problems, but there are all the icons missing. The biggest difference, which could lead to such a problem is the resolution since the LG has just 280x280 and the Asus 320x320. Can I address this with different icon folders like I would do it for Smartphones? I can't find any information related to the different resolutions in the google guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Please try going through [Wear App Quality](https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/wear.html). A couple of quality criteria are given which will help ensure a great user experience for your apps.

There are [Functionality](https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/wear.html#fn) criteria to ensure that your app is configured correctly and provides the expected functional behavior. These criteria must be checked specially for wearable apps that are dependent on a handheld app.

Aside from that, to provide a consistent, intuitive, and enjoyable user experience on wearables, [Visual Design and User Interaction](https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/wear.html#ux) have also criteria which ensure that your app follows critical design and interaction patterns.

I'm actually new to Android Wear so I hope that helps. Happy coding!